# Passing id in route producing uncallables

Tags: python, flask, routes

I am trying to transition my workflow into Flask to write a simple web interface for a Python script.

However, doing the following, raises a type error constantly:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import sqlite3
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/restart/<int:id>')
def restart(id):
    return id

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I would basically just like to show the id that is passed in the URL.

Am I missing something? This is exactly how I would do this in Django for example and all the examples on the Net have pointed to this approach in Flask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route function should be returning a string but you're returning the integer you're passing into it. Cast it to a string instead:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import sqlite3
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/restart/<int:id>')
def restart(id):
    return str(id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```